# copy a formula to the bottom of an active range when the range is only one row

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am using the following code to copy data down from a cell to the bottom of an active range after I put a formula or a Vlookup in the first cell.

```
Range("G2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,Order,108,FALSE)"
 Range("G2").Select
 LR = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
    Range("G2").AutoFill Range("G2:G" & LR)
```

This code works fine until I only have one row in the active range then I get an error to debug

Run-time Error '1004':
Autofill Method Range Class failed

What do I need to add when the last row is the first row?

Any Suggestions?

I use this line of code to copy to the active section several times in the same tab.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `If LR > 2 Then`?

Answer (score 0):

An `If` may be very useful in this case.

Try something like:

```
 Range("G2").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,Order,108,FALSE)"
 Range("G2").Select
 LR = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
 If LR <> 2 Then Range("G2").AutoFill Range("G2:G" & LR)
```